# Responses are received on different ports

Tags: websocket, firefox-addon-webextensions

As per [long lived connections](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) I'm using diffrent port to send message from client script thru background script to my nodejs sever using Websockets which takes upto 20 seconds to reply.

For example from client script:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "ping"});
  port.postMessage(Obj);

var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "specialprocessing"});
  port.postMessage(Obj);
```

I keep Websocket connection to Nodejs server open. But when I get response I'm getting in different ports than intended. That is `Ping` response is sometimes coming in "`specialprocessing`" port and vice versa.

Response are coming in in BG script:

```
websocket.onmessage()
```

I don't know how to handle this and this is creating a mess. Any solution to this mixup?

Comment: Sorry it's in Firefox webextension

Comment: Maybe your onConnect listener is incorrect. Otherwise sounds like a bug in Firefox.